# XPS 15 9550 with Ultrasharp 25 U2520D

Tags: displayport, dell-xps, thunderbolt

I am currently trying to get my Ultrasharp 25 U2520D to work with my XPS but had no luck so far.
Connecting the Monitor over Thunderbolt 3 doesn't seems to do a thing and I'm wondering why.

The specs say the 9550 Thunderbolt 3 only supports USB 3.1 Gen 2 or DisplayPort 1.2 whereas the Ultrasharp 25 specs say; "supports DisplayPort Alternate Mode (DP1.4 standard only)"

Am I right that this combo is not working and DP is not downwards-compatible? Another thunderbolt connection (Thunderbolt - DVI-D) has worked for another monitor so far.

Comment: Like stated, XPS 15 9550

Answer (score 0):

The
[Ultrasharp 25 U2520D](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/ultrasharp-25-usb-c-monitor-u2520d/apd/210-avkg/monitors-monitor-accessories#techspecs_section)
doesn't support Thunderbolt.

I suggest using DisplayPort, which is supported by both the monitor and the
[XPS 15 9550](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-XPS-15-2016-9550-InfinityEdge-Notebook-Review.156354.0.html).

Comment: How is DP not supported if other laptops can seemlesly establish connection via thunderbold to the monitor as shown in couple demos/videos? I thought thunderbold 3 integrates DP 1.2 or up to 1.4. So should I use a USB-c to DP cable after your suggestion?

Comment: The terms Thunderbolt and DisplayPort are distinct, but you might be mixing them up. There's no reason that a DP cable wouldn't work. But if you have trouble with yours, try something else.